# The inclusion $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Q$ is an epimorphism

Tags: category-theory

I am supposed to show that the inclusion of the integers in the rationals is an epimorphism in the category of abelian groups. Not only am I unable to find the right argument, I am starting to wonder if it is true at all.

Any thoughts or counter-examples?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the definition of epimorphism?

Comment: Doesn't epimorphism mean an "onto" function?

Comment: No, @Gregory, not in every category.

Comment: Yes. The point is to find epic mono that aren't isomorphisms and I have checked this for the same mapping, seen as a continuous application in the Top category. But I can't figure out how to show this one is epic.

Comment: @mdlt Done. ${}$

Comment: And my thanks to everyone.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi So you're saying epimorphism does not mean onto in the category of abelian groups?

Comment: @GregoryGrant In the category of abelian groups, epimorphisms are surjective maps. But in a general category, this needs not be the case (and the adjective "surjective" may not even make sense).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is false in the category of abelian groups. Consider the composition $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the exercise was meant for the category of *rings*. Then the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is indeed an epimorphism. See also the discussion on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266886/epimorphism-and-monomorphism-isomorphism). For the category of abelian groups, epimorphism and surjective morphism is the same.

Comment: Yes, I can see why for the category of rings. I will ask my professor if there is a typo.

Comment: Is it easy to see that abelian group epimorphisms are surjective?

Comment: Yes, for the category of $R$-modules this is easy. Abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

Comment: But this is because $\mathbb Z$ is principal, right?

Comment: No. $R$-modules are very nice for any ring $R$.

Comment: May I ask a question, How to prove that the inclusion $\mathbf{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbf{Q}$ is epimorphism? I don't see it obviously.