# A monomorphism and epimorphism that is neither injective nor surjective(set-theoretically)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monomorphisms, epimorphisms

Is it possible to construct a category such that there is a monomorphism and epimorphism that is neither injective nor surjective(set-theoretically).

I notice that there is a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/266887/185631) in which a monomorphism and epimorphism is not surjective. I wonder if a morphism always has to be "injective" as long as it is a monomorphism and epimorphism.

Comment: There are categories whose morphisms are not even maps; what would it mean for one of those to be "neither injective nor surjective"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I want a map which is neither surjective nor injective. Of course, the category is not "Set", in which the statement is true.

Comment: @TiWen The last sentence of your question suggests that you believe the morphisms of a category are set-theoretic functions maybe satisfying some properties or with extra structure. Henning is saying that this isn't the case.  For example, given a partial order $\leq$, you can make a category where $\text{Hom}(X,Y) = \{(X,Y)\}$ if $X \leq Y$ and $\{\}$ otherwise. A morphism in this category is just a pair of objects. What does it mean for a pair of objects to be "injective"? (Note, in this example all morphisms are mono and epi.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this silly category:

**Object:** Sets $A$ such that $\{0,1\}\subseteq A\subseteq \mathbb N$.

**Morphisms:** Maps $f:A\to B$ with the properties
$$ f(0)=f(1)=0 \\
x\notin\{0,1\}\Rightarrow f(x)\notin\{0,1\} $$

**Composition:** Function composition.

**Identity:** $\mathrm{id}(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if }x=1 \\ x & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Then *no morphism at all* is either injective or surjective as a map -- but there are plenty of epimorphisms and monomorphisms, such as all the identities.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for instance, define a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$ whose only objects are $$A=\{1,2\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\{3,4\}$$ and morphisms are given as $$\begin{align}\operatorname{Hom}(A,A)&=\{\operatorname{id}_A\},\\\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)&=\{f\},\\\operatorname{Hom}(B,A)&=\emptyset,\\\operatorname{Hom}(B,B)&=\{\operatorname{id}_B\},\end{align}$$ where $f:A\to B$ is defined by $f(1)=f(2)=3$. Then $f$ is a monomorphism and an epimorphism, but it is neither injective nor surjective.