# About monomorphisms and epimorphisms.

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, $a,b\in Ob(\mathcal{C})$ and $f,g\in Hom(a,b)$. If $f$ is monomorphism and $g$ epimorphism, can we say something about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Like what?$\quad$

Comment: @DerekElkins if they are isomorphics, for example.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266886/epimorphism-and-monomorphism-isomorphism) and [this also](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548641/monic-and-epic-implies-isomorphism-in-an-abelian-category).

Comment: @Krish those questions state that the same arrow is monomorphism and epimorphism, not here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the category freely generated by the graph $\bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet$. So we have objects $a,b$, morphisms $f : a \to b$, $g : a \to b$, and the identities. Here both $f$ and $g$ are monomorphisms and epimorphisms. But there is no isomorphism between $a$ and $b$.