# Morphism in both the category and dual category is isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

If I consider the category of sets with injective functions as morphisms, denote $Set_{\text{inj}}$, and $Set_{\text{sur}}$ the category of sets with surjective functions as morphisms, I think it is true that $\Big( Set_{\text{inj}} \Big)^{op}=Set_{\text{sur}}$, and that if $h$ is a morphism in both categories then it is an isomorphism.

Is it true that if a morphism is both in the category and the dual category, then it is an isomorphism? Is it perhaps true when we also assume that the category $\mathcal{C}$ satisfies the Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein property?

Comment: It’s not true that the category of sets/injections is (or even is equivalent to) the opposite of the category of sets/injections. For example there is a set (the empty sets) with no surjections from any non-isomorphic set, but there is no set with the “dual” property of having no injections to any non-isomorphic set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking of equality between categories is not the right way to think about it. This heavily depends on how you exactly code the data of a category. A better question would be to ask if the categories are isomorphic, or even better: equivalent.

So let's make your claim more precise in this way: you claim that there is an isomorphism of categories $F: (\mathbf{Set}_{inj})^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}_{sur}$ that is the identity on objects. This cannot be true. In $\mathbf{Set}_{sur}$ the empty set is disconnected from the rest of the category: there are no arrows with domain or codomain $\emptyset$, other than the identity arrow. On the other hand, in $\mathbf{Set}_{inj}$ we have an arrow $\emptyset \to X$ for every set $X$. In fact, this means that there cannot even be a functor $F: (\mathbf{Set}_{inj})^{op} \to \mathbf{Set}_{sur}$ such that $F(\emptyset) = \emptyset$.

Unfortunately, the rest of your question is not precise enough to answer. You seem to be interested in the fact that in $\mathbf{Set}$ we have that an injective and surjective function is a bijection. So in category-theoretic terms: an arrow that is a monomorphism and epimorphism is an isomorphism. This is not generally true in categories, but there are reasonable assumptions where it does work (e.g. one of the morphisms is regular). See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266886/epimorphism-and-monomorphism-isomorphism) for more details.